# jquery function called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js files. In the first one I have this:

```
var functionName = "video"; 
var cont = 1;

$(function() { 
    window.control = function control() {   
        var tipo1 = functionName + cont + "();";
        var tipo2 = eval(tipo1);
        tipo2;
        cont++;
    });
```

In the second one:

```
function video1() {
    control();
}

function video2() {
    control();
}
```

The first time was fine, but in the second, first execute `video1()` and then `video2()`, why?

Comment: This isn't going to fix the issue, but please don't use `eval()`. Try `window[tipo1]();` instead. Note you may need to change `window` depending on your logic structure.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but if I call window[tipo1](); there is an error in console: "window[tipo1] is not a function"

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is wrong:

```
window.control = function control() {
```

I imagine because of this it's firing `control()` execution.

Change this to:

```
window.control = function() {
```

---

Also I see no reason for defining this function at DOM ready state. It will just cause confusion and potential reference issues. The definition of a function is only ran at execution point, these should potentially be on DOM ready state depending on their use.

Comment: thanks, but don't use to me. I remove window and I just have function control(). But it is the same, first execute video1 and then video2.